# Eclipse HTML tags autocomplete

Tags: html, eclipse, visual-studio-2012, autocomplete, tags

so i have downloaded **Eclipse Juno with WPT (Web Platform Tools) also with PDT (Php Development Tools)** after years of coding with Microsoft's Visual Studio. i am a web developer and the editor in Visual Studio is very comfortable for me , in Visual Studio you can write an HTML tag and as soon as **you press the `>` character it autocompletes the tag.**

but ***in eclipse this feature only works for certain tags (eg : `table` , `div` , `a`  , and so on...)
but when i write a `tr` tag or a `td` it will not autocomplete it.***

please help.
I am very spoiled in terms of code editors i guess...

Comment: Maybe check out emmet? - http://emmet.io/download/ although if you're doing HTML/CSS then you might consider using a text editor, rather than a full blown IDE - Sublime Text does me nicely!

Comment: thanks but i'm also working with php and Jquery , so i need the intellisense